# SPFX- Can not run gulp ser for the first time

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint, gulp, spfx

I face this issue when I run gulp serve for the first time :

Error: Cannot find module '@rushstack/module-minifier-plugin'

Plz help me, Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check your node_modules folder first.

When you install npm packages, npm will create a node_modules folder in your project root. It will also add packages you’ve installed to your package.json and package-lock.json files.You can confirm that a package has been installed by making sure it’s listed in your package and package-lock.json files. And double-check your node_modules folder to make sure the package is in a subfolder there.

2.Install the module.

As your gulp is complaining about the package missing,add it to your package.json and run **npm install**.